# Detect an application that has not sent a message in the last 15 minutes using Kapacitor

Tags: kapacitor

We are writing a message count per application to InfluxDb every 10 seconds. I want to be able to generate an alert if that number has not changed in the last 15 minutes.

I tried derivative, but that gives the change for each data point. The unit parameter just scales the result. Derivative works well for our chattier apps where we can check if a message was sent every 10s, but the 15 minute window is not working.

I tried using spread with a batched query grouped by time, but that gives me the change in whole quarters of the hour (00 to 15, 15:01 to 30, 30:01 to 45...). I want to be able to check the last 15 minutes and check it every minute or so.

I tried using a windowed stream with spread, but it seems to be grabbing points outside the window since it is giving a non-zero answer.

Comment: Can you include a snippet of the TICKscript for `I tried using a windowed stream with spread, but it seems to be grabbing points outside the window since it is giving a non-zero answer.` I'm surprised that this didn't work.

Comment: May I jump in with a script attempting the same thing, but which I cannot get to work?  `var data = batch
        |query(''' select * from "mydb"."autogen"."myMeasurement" where application='myMeasurement'  ''')
                .period(5m)
                .every(1m)

data
        |deadman(1, 5m)
                .slack()
                .message('No myMeasurement data for myMeasurement for 5 minutes in non-prod.')
                .channel('#test-alert-myTeamName')`

Comment: Am trying to just trigger an alert if receiving < 1 record in 5 minutes.  Our Influx DBA team requests that we do not write streaming queries because something something performance reasons that I forgot something something.

Comment: Currently, this script constantly triggers alerts even when we have 1 record being inserted exactly every minute. And I can paste the contents of the query node here into a separate influx query and see that it does indeed return the expected data.

Comment: kapacitor's deadman's switch may help the scenario: https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/latest/nodes/stream_node/#deadman